# SQL Server joining two tables, order by and display one record

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am having trouble with a SQL Server statement. The perfect scenario is the order and another table (jobs) by date created then display the contact information in descending order. Currently I can get the script to show all records, however if the user has more than one job then they are displayed more than once.

```
SELECT 
    c.*,
    p.date_created
FROM 
    [db].[dbo].[Contact] AS c
JOIN 
    [db].[dbo].[job] AS p ON p.contact_id = c.contact_id  

UNION

SELECT 
    *,
    0 as date_created 
FROM
    [db].[dbo].[Contact]   
ORDER BY 
    p.date_created DESC
```

The output

```
contact_id| date_created         | contact_name         
1         | 8/29/2016 1:07:18 PM | sam  
1         | 8/26/2016 1:04:01 PM | sam 
14        | 8/24/2016 5:07:22 PM | steve
```

The final output should just show the newest date created and for one user. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: That's not going to be the output of that query. Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: You should group by contact_id, contact_name and aggregate CreatedDate column p.e with max(CreatedDate)

Comment: Before he should fix the problem in the 2nd sub-query where he tries to select 0 as a date. Then he can apply the max function grouping by contact_id and contact_name. However a more precise example of output will be appreciated.

Comment: i cant output all of the columns as it contains sensitive data. i have corrected the 0 to a convert to datatime. how would i go about grouping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column in union select must match for number and type so convert 0 in a proper date

```
    SELECT 
         c.contact_id
         ,max(p.date_created)
         ,c. contact_name         
    FROM [db].[dbo].[Contact] AS c
    JOIN [db].[dbo].[job] AS p 
        ON p.contact_id = c.contact_id 
    GROUP BY  c.contact_id,c. contact_name 
    union
    select  
         c.contact_id
        ,   convert(datetime, '01/01/1070', 101) as date_created
        , c. contact_name  
    from [db].[dbo].[Contact]   
    ORDER BY p.date_created desc`
```

The result you need anyway should be obtainable with only

```
    SELECT 
         c.contact_id
         ,max(p.date_created) as max_date_created
         ,c. contact_name         
    FROM [db].[dbo].[Contact] AS c
    LEFT JOIN [db].[dbo].[job] AS p 
        ON p.contact_id = c.contact_id 
    GROUP BY  c.contact_id,c. contact_name 
    ORDER BY  c.contact_id,c. contact_name, max_date_created
```

Comment: i tired this and no luck, still shows more than one row with the same contact_id. Also i think you forgot to close the brackets of the convert

Comment: I have update the answer ...but i can't understand the use or the second select in union ..

Comment: that works, however i need it to show all other contacts after. this only shows contacts that have a date_created in job. Thanks for helping.

Comment: rated as its useful, do you know how to display all other contacts underneath the ordered date_created?

Comment: can not understand what you get .. and try to explain better and possibly give me an example that I can understand ..

Comment: i basically want to select all of the contacts but order by date_created from another table. your example works well however doesn't list all of the contacts.

Comment: My second query should show all the distinct name in your tables?  .. and for each name should show only a row with the max(date_created)  -- You are say that not all distinct name are selected or that you don't want only the max(date:careate) ?

Comment: its shows all of the contacts that have a job, however i wish it to show all contacts even if they dont have job. but its ordered by date_created. does that make sense? so all the other will essentially be null

Comment: I have update the answer with left join  .. and order by